# Netbeans environment variables for C++ makefile

Tags: c++, macos, netbeans, makefile

I have a simple makefile which calls the C++ compiler as `$(CXX)`, which is set in my `~/.profile` script. Netbeans seems to have a sophisticated toolchain manager, yet it seems to resolve `$CXX` as just `c++` no matter what.

How can I set `$CXX` properly, or is there another variable set by Netbeans that my makefile can detect? (yuck)

Edit: right-clicking the makefile in the navigator allows me to specify an environment, although there seems to be only room for one line of input. Specifying `CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++` fixes the problem, but this is far from optimal.

Comment: You can specify per file compile options, so if you right click on a file you can specify it as a `c` file or a `c++` file... To choose a compiler you need to make a `toolkit`.

Comment: @Mikhail This is a custom makefile, so Netbeans can't do anything per file.

Comment: Maybe you could change your makefile? Also you do a custom invocation to the makefile, but I think you need to just choose the right `toolset`.

Comment: @Mikhail Yes, this question is about how I can properly select the toolset or change the makefile to reflect the toolset.

Comment: I have a similar problem - make won't pick up environment settings that are set in my bash_profile. Outside the makefile they are set, which can be shown with `echo $VARIABLE`, but inside the makefile `$(info $VARIABLE)` prints an empty line. Any idea?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out: I forgot to put "export" in front of that particular line in the bash_profile. I also put all the initializations from bash_profile into bashrc and source that from the profile script in order to have the variables ready for non-interactive shells (not sure whether that is needed for GNU Make)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll just describe what I usually do when I work with C++ in NetBeans. At first, for each project I create a simple makefile like this:

```
MAIN = <my main target>
CFLAGS = -g -std=c++0x

include ${MAKELIBHOME}/MINGW32.inc
include ${MAKELIBHOME}/WINDOWS.inc

build: ${MAIN}

clean:; rm -fr <files to remove>
```

The environment variable MAKELIBHOME is set outside of NetBeans. The directory ${MAKELIBHOME} contains a number of *include files* for the make, for example the file MINGW32.inc looks like this:

```
CC = g++

CFLAGS += -W -DLITTLE_ENDIAN=1
LDLIBS += -lws2_32

.SUFFIXES: .o .c .cpp

.c:     ;${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} $< -o latest ${LDLIBS}
.cpp:   ;${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} $< -o latest ${LDLIBS}

.c.o:   ;${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $<
.cpp.o: ;${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $<
```

These inc-files are the same for all NetBeans projects. There are no absolute paths here, so the make will use the PATH variable to locate a GCC toolset, but of course you can use absolute paths to choose the toolset you like (or include a different inc-file - I'd prefer this way).

All this works on my Windows machine, but the Linux configuration looks very similar - I just need to include another set of inc-files to all my main makefiles. Also, this setup allows me to call the make from the command line.

I hope it helps,
~AY

Comment: Hmm, I missed this when you posted it. I don't use NetBeans any more, but my question is on "The environment variable `MAKELIBHOME` is set outside of NetBeans." *How* did you make an external environment variable visible to NetBeans? Although, since I'm on Unix/OS X, it might not translate over.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - the `make` can refer to environment variables in both Windows and Unix, and it happens outside of NetBeans. BTW, I always use the NetBeans project type "C/C++ Project With Existing Sources", so my `Makefile` is totally under my control

Comment: Well, as the question states, my `.profile` did set `$CXX` but the variable was not available to the makefile. The program that invokes `make` is responsible for creating the environment, although it's true that variables propagate by default.

Comment: I looked at my makefiles again - so, makefiles on my old Windows XP system do refer to the `MAKELIBHOME` environment variable, which has been set (interactively) before. However, makefiles on my newer Ubuntu system assign the `MAKELIBHOME` variable inside them. Actually I have `ifeq (${OS},Windows_NT)` condition in all my makefiles to make this kind of branching automatic. So - you are right, the NetBeans on Unix behaves differently

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post. However I found the same problem recently and I found an alternative based on @HEKTO's answer.

I use PETSc, a library to solve large sparse matrix systems. Their build system requires you to use an "include" in your makefile which depends on two environment variables: PETSC_DIR and PETSC_ARCH which must be set in your environment.... or you can pass them as options to your make command!! this is what I did.

I took the makefile generated by NetBeans and at the very end I added my include:

```
include ${PETSC_DIR}/conf/variables
```

Notice how this depends on the definition of PETSC_DIR. In addition this include massively uses this and PETSC_ARCH all over the place.

So, in NetBeans now I configure it to pass these variables to make:
Tools->Options: In the "Project Options" tab I fill the text box for "Make Options" to be: PETSC_DIR=/path/to/petsc PETSC_ARCH=some-arch

Also, now you can start using these environment variables (and others defined in ${PETSC_DIR}/conf/variables within your project options. For instance, for my include files I do (right click on project, then "Properties"):
Under "C Compiler", "Include Directories" I put: ${PETSC_DIR}/include

And under "Linker", "Libraries" I put: ${PETSC_LIB} (defined in the include file above).

Now I can build and run my project from within NetBeans. If my PETSc version changes I only need to change the definition of the variables passed to make and everything else gets resolved.

I hope this might help somebody. It definitely worked for me. And the nice part is that I can give my code to other people and they can compile from the command line using "make" as usual (without NetBeans) and defining the above environment variables. The compilation now does not have any hard coded paths.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem on linux, where Netbeans didn't grab the Environment variables from bash.

The solution: start netbeans from bash.

I'm not sure what the equivalent is on Mac, but the idea is simple: start Netbeans from a terminal that has the right environment variables already set.